# How to Use Menu in Complete Application in Android

Tags: android, menu, navigation

I am working on an application in android. Where I need to use menu through out application. Actually it will be used for navigating within application from one activity to other and so on... I am  wondering that it will need to write **onOptionMenuCreat** and **OnOptionMenuSelect** methods in each activity. **Also if I make one parent activity where these two methods could be written even then on each activity Option Menu will be created again.** So handling same menu while it is created again is becoming work of afaik. Any good design suggestions are most welcomed. Another very important thing how to map that user was on witch activity last time while selecting same menu again. My app has total five menu options so that means there are five different ways to move within application simultaneously.

Please Do tell me solution for both issues. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the Menu in an Activity and inherit all the other Activities from this Activity.

To answer the second part.

create a different method for each menu handling in the parent activity. If you need a different menu/menu_item behaviour for your activity, just override that method.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your quick response. I am doing inheritance as you mentioned. My question is the why OnOptionMenuCreate will be called each time new activity inherits the parent. As same menu needs to be used through the ""Aplication"" to navigate and mapping "Who was where."?

Comment: @rai Well. As far the activity is concerned, it will not know if you have overridden the method in your subactivity. (Please see second part of my answer). I guess the simplest way for Android to ensure that the menu activity is correctly loaded is to reload them whenever a new activity instance is created.

Comment: Thank you. Let me implement and check the way you suggest. Thankx